# Authenticating Android app with PassportJS

Tags: android, node.js, express, passport.js

I have been using passportjs for user authentication on my web application. Now, I am working on Android Client for same project. When I logged in with local strategy, I was successfully logged in on Android. However, after logging in, when I tried to get data from another URI on my server, I got 'Invalid Username or Password'.

When I checked req, there was no req.user object when android asked for data on a particular URI. When accessing the same URI from web application, it contained the user data on req.user object. There was nothing in the case of Android.

I learnt that for Android, we do token-based authentication. Then I came across bearer strategy in passport js. It had some options of redirect URLs. I think I can't handle redirect URLs in Android App.
I have already done a lot of work using passport local strategy. Kindly, let me know what should I do or look into if I want to use the same strategy for my android application too.

Comment: What's the Final Solution? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ if you do session based authentication and Android Account manager if you do token-based authentication. I had switched to token based authentication later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer to my this question on following thread. Posting it here, it might help someone else.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+SojharoMangi/posts/N1d5XQawSnU

Comment: You used token based authentication using passport.js? Is it same as Oauth

Comment: Google+ is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search i found this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-facebook-token